# C++ Inheritance with Interface and Default Implementation

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions

I'm not exactly sure what to call this inheritance scheme, but I'm trying to use a  `cloneable` interface with a default implementation. I'm having some issues getting the correct scheme though.

I'm basing this somewhat on the cloneable interface defined in C#.

First I have my interface and default implementations:

```
template<class BaseType>
class ICloneable
{
public:
    virtual std::shared_ptr<BaseType> Clone() const = 0;
};

template<class BaseType, class DerivedType>
class Cloneable : public ICloneable<BaseType>
{
public:
    virtual std::shared_ptr<BaseType> Clone() const
    {
        return std::shared_ptr<BaseType>(new DerivedType(*(DerivedType*)this));
    }
};
```

My desire is to have the following scheme.

```
// A pure virtual base interface
class Base : public ICloneable<Base>
{
public:
    virtual void SomeFunc() = 0;
}

// Another implementation
class Imp1 : public Base, Cloneable<Base, Imp1>
{
    public:
        virtual void SomeFunc() {}
}
// An implementation
class Imp2 : public Cloneable<Base, Imp2>
{
    public:
        virtual void SomeFunc() {}
}
```

If I have a list of `std::shared_ptr' objects, I can invoke the Clone function when I want to make a deep copy without having to manually write the function in every one of the implementations.

Right now I get that Imp is an abstract class, which doesn't surprise me. **Anyone know how I can get this default implementation idea to work?** The point is to not have to manually write the clone function for every one of the implementations. It might not be doable but I'm out of ideas to try.

Comment: Before you wander too far down this path, are you certain you need to use `shared_ptr` and cloning at all or is this a side-effect of C# as a first language? Are you trying to solve the problem in C++ the same way you would in C# when C++ may have a more-applicable idiom?

Comment: The pointer you return is unique. Unless you want to explicitly allow an object to return a pointer that it keeps a copy of, use a `std::unique_ptr`. If caller wants to share it once it gets it, it will be able to do so easily and efficiently.

Comment: C++ is not C#. Whatever XY problem this may or may not solve, the explicit `(DerivedType*)` cast is going to break type-safety, and will be an endless source of pains. Some other, type-safe approach should be used for this.

Comment: The shared_ptr is for other reasons than this issue. Returning a shared_ptr here is not necessary, a normal pointer would do, but the issue remains. Whether I return a `Base*` or `shared_ptr<Base>` from `Clone()` nothing changes.

Comment: I shouldn't have mentioned C# because now everyone's answer will be "Ahh, he mentioned C#, noob."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
#include <memory>

template<typename InterfaceType_>
struct ICloneable
{
    using InterfaceType = InterfaceType_;

    virtual ~ICloneable() = default;

    virtual std::shared_ptr<InterfaceType> clone() const = 0;
};

template<typename T, typename Base = ICloneable<T>>
struct CloneableMixin : public Base
{
    using InterfaceType = typename Base::InterfaceType;

    // With the following line uncommented, code does not compile in MSVC
    //using typename Base::InterfaceType;

    std::shared_ptr<InterfaceType> clone() const override
    { return std::make_shared<T>(*static_cast<const T*>(this)); }
};
```

Now, this can be used as follows:

```
struct SomeBaseClass : public CloneableMixin<SomeBaseClass> { /*...*/ };

struct SomeDerivedClass : public CloneableMixin<SomeDerivedClass, SomeBaseClass> { /*...*/ };
```

Two notes:

- In order to be able to access `InterfaceType_` template parameter of `ICloneable`, you need to make it a template alias, and then use `using typename Base::InterfaceType` (as it is template parameter dependent type).
- I've provided default type for `Base` template parameter of `CloneableMixin` - this allows to use it for base classes, for which you want to have `clone` implemented.

Moreover, two unrelated comments:

- You don't need to type `virtual` - it's implied. It's a good idea to add `override` at the end (this makes sure that the method actually overrides something, otherwise a compiler will report an error).
- You might consider using [`std::make_shared`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) instead of `new`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm testing this out now. I'm not using `make_shared` because this needs to be compatible with some older gcc versions which don't support it.

Comment: I'm getting an error that   Error 29 error C2039: 'InterfaceType' : is not a member of '{name of the derived class}'

Comment: @RussellTrahan you can implement your own make shared using c++11 (minus some of the memory optimization) to make sure you don’t leak memory.

Comment: @RussellTrahan: This seems to be a problem with MSVC. I've edited the example to make it work with it.

Comment: It looks like the key to making it work was to put `: public Base` within the Cloneable class instead of  on the Imp class as you would normally do.